# How do we use the epsilon-delta notations in the context of a limit of a sequence of sets?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, notation, epsilon-delta, interval-arithmetic

This is in the context of "set theory" and "sequence of sets" and their corresponding notations.

I was trying to solve a question which says:

- $C_1, C_2, C_3 \dots$ is a non-decreasing sequence of sets, i.e., ${C_k} \subset C_{k+1}\space$for $k = 1, 2, 3\dots$ ; and
- $\lim \limits_{k\space\to\space\infty}C_k$ is defined as the union $\space C_1 \cup C_2 \cup C_3\dots\space$ = $\bigcup_ \limits{n\space=\space1}^\infty C_n\space$for $n = 1, 2, 3 \dots\space$.

What is $\lim \limits_{k\space\to\space\infty}C_k$ where $C_k = \big\{x:\frac{1}{k} \le x \le 4-\frac{1}{k^2}\big\}\space$for $k = 1, 2, 3 \dots\space$?

––––––––––––––––––––

I approached the problem as follows:

Since $C_k = \big\{x:\frac{1}{k} \le x \le 4-\frac{1}{k^2}\big\}\space$for $k = 1, 2, 3 \dots\space$; we have,

$C_1 = \big\{x:1 \le x \le 3\big\}\space \implies \space x\in \left[1,\space3\right]$ for $C_1$,

$C_2 = \big\{x:\frac{1}{4} \le x \le \frac{15}{4}\big\}\space \implies \space x\in \left[\frac{1}{4},\space\frac{15}{4}\right]$ for $C_2$,

and so on.

Hence,

$\begin{align}
\lim \limits_{k\space\to\infty}C_k &= \bigg\{x:\bigg(\lim \limits_{k\space\to\space\infty}\frac{1}{k}\bigg) \le x \le \bigg(\lim \limits_{k\space\to\infty}\big(4-\frac{1}{k^2}\big)\bigg)\bigg\} \\
&=\bigg\{x:\epsilon \le x \le 4-\delta\bigg\}
\end{align}$

where $\space\epsilon\to0$, $\space\epsilon > 0$,

and $\space\delta\to0$, $\space\delta > 0$.

So, for $\lim \limits_{k\space\to\space\infty}C_k\space$,$\space$ we have, $\space$$x\in \left[\epsilon,\space4-\delta\right]\space$ where $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ are infinitesimals.

The interval $\left[\epsilon,\space4-\delta\right]$ is better represented by the interval $\left(0,\space4\right)$.

Hence the answer is $\lim \limits_{k\space\to\space\infty}C_k = x$ where $x \in (0,\space4)$.

––––––––––––––––––––

My questions are:

- Is my approach correct? Is there a different way to understand and solve this question?
- Are my notations correct for the lines involving the "infinitesimals" along with the "belongs to" and the "less than or equal to" symbols for sets and/or intervals (like the ones below)?

  - $\bigg\{x:\bigg(\lim \limits_{k\space\to\space\infty}\frac{1}{k}\bigg) \le x \le \bigg(\lim \limits_{k\space\to\infty}\big(4-\frac{1}{k^2}\big)\bigg)\bigg\}$
  - $\bigg\{x:\epsilon \le x \le 4-\delta\bigg\}$
  - $x\in \left[\epsilon,\space4-\delta\right]$ where $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ are infinitesimals.
  - The interval $\left[\epsilon,\space4-\delta\right]$ is better represented by the interval $\left(0,\space4\right)$.

Comment: Epsilon/delta definition of the limit only works for metric spaces, where there’s a notion of a distance. With generic sets you don’t have that, that’s why there’s no epsilon/delta definition of a limit of a sequence of sets. Actually, I don’t think there any definition of a limit for an arbitrary sequence of sets. There are for upper and lower limits though.

Comment: As a first step, tell us how do you define the limit of a sequence of subsets of a set.

Comment: Tangential side note: You can give measurable sets a metric topology. Any finite measure space has an associated Nikodym metric space!

Comment: $\lim C_k=(0,4)$ is correct. $\lim_k C_k=x$ is not correct

Comment: @jose They did tell us. It's right there in the question: “$\lim_{k\to\infty} C_k$ is defined as…”.

Comment: Hi @JoséCarlosSantos I was going through Introduction to Mathematical Statistics by Hogg, McKean, Craig (8th edition), where it is mentioned a sequence of sets is non-decreasing if ${A_n} \subset A_{n+1}\space$ for $n = 1, 2, 3\dots$ and for such sets, the definition of limit of a sequence of sets is $\lim \limits_{n\space\to\space\infty}A_n = \bigcup_ \limits{n\space=\space1}^\infty A_n\space$. It's not about the limit of a sequence of subsets of a set.

Comment: @koustav_ch If that's your definition, then why don't you use it, instead of using $\varepsilon$'s and $\delta$'s?

Comment: Thank you @FShrike for showing the correct notation. What about the other notations? Are there some mistakes in them?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos So you mean I should be doing $\lim \limits_{k\space\to\space\infty}C_k = \left[1,\space3\right] \cup \left[\frac{1}{4},\space\frac{15}{4}\right]\space\cup\space\dots\space\cup\bigg[{\bigg(\lim \limits_{k\space\to\space\infty}\frac{1}{k}\bigg), \bigg(\lim \limits_{k\space\to\infty}\big(4-\frac{1}{k^2}\big)\bigg)\bigg]}$. Is that notation correct (the last set/interval)?

Comment: No; it should be$$\lim_{k\to\infty}C_k=[1,3]\cup\left[\frac12,\frac{15}4\right]\cup\cdots=(0,4).$$

Comment: You have something named $\epsilon$ and something named $\delta,$ but that alone doesn't make this an epsilon-delta proof. An epsilon-delta proof requires $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ to be related to each other in a way that is completely absent here. In fact I would say that you cannot have an epsilon-delta proof unless you can embed the classic epsilon-delta definition of a limit into your proof and still have it make sense.

Comment: It seems to me that from a couple of examples you have jumped to the conclusion that $\lim_{k\to\infty}C_k = \left\{x:\left(\lim_{k\to\space\infty}\frac{1}{k}\right) \le x \le \left(\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(4-\frac{1}{k^2}\right)\right)\right\}$. If you want to use this fact, you have to prove it. (If you absolutely **insist** on going back to basics, you can then use epsilon-delta twice, once for the limit of $1/k$ and once for the limit of $4-1/k^2.$) However, that kind of proof seems a lot harder than the standard method for a limit of nested sets, which is shown in FShrike's answer.

Comment: @DavidK Yes, that is the conclusion that I have drawn. However, I was not sure whether I can use the $\le$ notation along with the limits or should it be a $<$ notation. I agree with you that for a detailed calculation of those two limits, I need to use the epsilon-delta twice. Here, I simply used epsilon and delta to denote two separate infinitesimals ($\lim_{k\to\space\infty}\frac{1}{k}$ and $\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(4-\frac{1}{k^2}\right)$).

Comment: Now that you mention it, you **cannot** prove the $\leq$ statement, because it is false. The limit of $1/k$ is not an infinitesimal; it's zero. You would have to use $<.$ And it is confusing that you say "epsilon-delta" (which has a very specific connotation) in the title but then the body of the question is all about infinitesimals, which is a way of **not** doing epsilon-delta proofs.

Comment: @DavidK I understand now. Using $\le$ or $\ge$ is not correct while taking about infinitesimals. It is similar to how we write $x \ge 0$ as the interval $x \in \left[0, \infty\right)$ and not as $x \in \left[0, \infty\right]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would completely avoid a discussion of infinitesimals. Much more simply, an element $x$ is in the union of the $C_k$ iff. it is in *one* $C_k$ for some $k$. If $x\in(0,4)$, then there are large enough $k$ that $1/k\le x\le4-1/k^2$. So $(0,4)\subseteq\lim C_k$.

If $x\le 0$, then for no finite positive $k$ can we have $1/k\le x$. Likewise, if $x\ge4$ then $x$ cannot be in any of the individual sets $C_k$ and therefore is not in their union. So $(0,4)=\lim C_k$.

It is not right to say $(0,4)=[\epsilon,4-\delta]$ for some “infinitesimals”. Infinitesimals are really rather tricky to rigorously define, and are generally not needed. They are certainly not needed here, and I doubt their use is even correct here. After all, $[\cdots]$ shall be a closed interval but $(\cdots)$ an open one.

Notions of “limit of a set” must not be conflated with the limits in real analysis or general topology. Rather they are conveying a similar idea: that does not mean your approach to understand them must also involve $\epsilon,\delta$. This concept of a limit of a sequence of sets can be applied in any general set: real numbers need not apply.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, especially for the last two paragraphs. I was thinking that I should find $\lim \limits_{k\space\to\space\infty}\bigg(\frac{1}{k}\bigg)$ and $\lim \limits_{k\space\to\space\infty}\bigg(4-\frac{1}{k^2}\bigg)$ separately and then try and use those to create a set/interval. Now I'm understanding this much better.

Comment: @koustav_ch You're welcome. Similar examples to ponder: $$\begin{align}\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\left(-\frac{1}{n},4+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)&=\color{red}{[}0,4\color{red}{]}\\\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty[n,\infty)&=\emptyset\\\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\{n\}&=\Bbb N\\\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty\bigcup_{n=k}^\infty\left[0,\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right]&=\{0\}\end{align}$$The last one is using the commonly appearing - e.g. see the Borel Cantelli lemma - "limsup" for sets. You need to read $[0,-1]$ as equal to $[-1,0]$ (to keep the notation clean)